# Watir Prevent Redirection

Tags: watir-webdriver

How do you prevent Watir from redirecting?  I have a site where users can paste a url and I retrieve images from it.  Sometimes I'm seeing that the url is redirected to another page (i.e.advertising a special).

I'm able to make it work like this:

```
 b = Watir::Browser.new :phantomjs
 b.goto my_url
 browser.back if b.url != my_url
```

but it's not very elegant.  I was hoping there was a property similar to what Mechanize has:

```
agent = Mechanize.new { |agent| agent.user_agent_alias = 'Mac Safari' }
agent.redirect_ok = false
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Watir does not have an option for preventing a redirect.

Watir drives the browser the same way a real user would. As a real user does not choose whether or not to follow redirects, neither does Watir.